# Anonymous types alternative in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way I can construct a query that will return not just existing entities on the model/table, but also create new variables populated according to a function/query. All done in a single query.

So something like this pseudocode.

```
Job::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $pdate)
    ->with('address')
    ->with('Employees'->count() as newprop);
```

Basically I want to get the job, address and also create a new property on the returned objects in the collection that will hold the employee count for each job.
What is the best way of going about this ? Maybe I should just create a new function/property on the Job model that returns Employees count ? Would that mean the application will make more db queries or will such property be populated anytime I use eloquent to get any Job object ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it to all Job model instances:

```
public function getNewpropAttribute($value) {
    return count($employees);
}
```

That way you can call `Job::find($id)->newprop;` and it will execute that function. it is described here https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: That works if I explicitly call getNewpropAttribute accessor with Job::find($id)->new prop; What about if I am just getting a collection of jobs and shooting them off to the front-end with json. As in, how can I get it to create an employee_count attribute with correct count set on each job object.